# Split up a delete query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

There is a table `a` that has many relationships with other tables.
On some of these relationships the `casade delete rule` has been set.

I'm trying to clear the table `a` from all data but am running into several issues when using `delete from a`

- The deletion process is very very slow
- The transaction log is filling up (disk space is an issue here.) making the query hang.

I've temp. placed the DB into Simple Recovery mode but the issue with the tran.log persists.

I've been thinking about splitting up the delete query but haven't found a quicker way yet. Tried `top()` en tried splitting up ID's with the `where clause`.

Anyone got any tips to empty this table faster?

Comment: `disk space is an issue here` <= Ensure there is more disk space or use a cursor to loop over batches of XXX size and delete them that way. The transaction log will always need room for whatever transaction it is working on so it can roll back in the event of failure. The memory is freed once each transaction is completed (in simple recovery mode). Disc space will not be freed though, only the room in the allocated space will be freed.

Comment: `Anyone got any tips to empty this table faster?` <= profile the delete query to see what is actually happening. It might also be indexes or statistics that have to be updated. It could be delete triggers. It could be the delete query itself.

Comment: drop all foreign keys to this table, use truncate table to delete the data, and re-create foreign keys.

Comment: @ZoharPeled this won't get the data deleted in the relevant relationship tables.

Comment: @Igor Atm I can't expand disk space, thats why I put it to Simple and want to delete it in batches. But even a top(100) makes a huge transaction log. Any tips on how to delete it in batches?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've build the following script to split the deletion in chunks and report back the status in the Messages tab based on the primary key 'id'.

```
DECLARE @countid int;
DECLARE @remaining int;
DECLARE @aantal int;
DECLARE @msg varchar(200);
SET @aantal = 100 -- Ammount that has to be deleted
SET @remaining = (select count(*) from Table);
SET @countid = (select MIN(id) + 100 from Table);

WHILE @remaining > 0
    BEGIN

        SET @msg = ('Remaining rows: ' + cast(@remaining as Varchar));
        raiserror (@msg,0,1) with nowait

        DELETE FROM Table
            WHERE id < @countid

        SET @remaining = @remaining - @@ROWCOUNT    
        SET @countid = @countid + @aantal

  CHECKPOINT -- Since the Recovery Model is Simple this clears the transaction log
END
```